# R file to be saved online and edit on difference devices?

Tags: r

Is there any method/way that a R file created on a local computer that can be saved online, retrieved on another machine to be edited and saved again much like google drive for word, excel etc?

This is because I am using a desktop computer at work and after work I wish to access the same file on my personal laptop much like the function of google sheet, excel but I am using R studio installed on both devices?

Comment: There is a googledrive package - would that help? https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/

Comment: You can store R files in the cloud like any other files. However, the recommended way is using a version control system (e.g., git) with an online repository (e.g., github). RStudio offers git integration.